# entity framework cache refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-framework, caching, code-first

Is there an equivalent to this Rails brilliance for clearing a DB query cache in Entity Framework (any version)?  I keep having this problem and can't seem to find an easy way to solve it:

> All of the association methods are built around caching, which keeps the result of the most recent query available for further operations. The cache is even shared across methods....
>
> But what if you want to reload the cache, because data might have been changed by some other part of the application? Just pass true to the association call:

```
customer.orders                 # retrieves orders from the database
customer.orders.size            # uses the cached copy of orders
customer.orders(true).empty?    # discards the cached copy of orders
                                # and goes back to the database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but those methods are not available directly on entity. You must interact with context to achieve this.

If you need to reload just single instance you can use:

```
dbContext.Entry(order).Reload();
```

If you need to reload multiple instances by single call you probably need to use ObjectContext API:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, customer.Orders);
```

Another approach is to run the query instead of using `Refresh` but that requires you to explicitly build a query to load correct orders:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Order>();
objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
objectSet.Where(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id).ToList();
```

The main differences between query and `Refresh` will be performance (`Refresh` will probably use separate query for each order in collection) and new entities (refresh reloads only entities you specify whereas query will load new as well).